# aufill range cells default value, when input range cell return to default

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

how to make autofill certain cell to its default value

Sheet "Single"

Range Cell C10:C20.

Default value blank (" ")

if I input "yes" on C10. The C11:C20 value (still) blank

Then I input "yes" at another cell, example C20. Value at C10 return to blank. And C11:C19 value (still) blank

> at 1st everthing is at Default Value

[image: First condition]

> 1st Manual input C13 "Yes, other cell still its default value

[image: 1st manual input]

> 2nd manual input C17 "yes", C13 return to default Value

[[image: 3rd manual input3]

Comment: Hi I would like to confirm if your goal is that whenever a cell in C10:C20 is set to "yes" other remaining cells will be set to blank/default value. Therefore, ONLY ONE cells is expected to have a value in C10:C20?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @RonM Yes sir, you got my point. there is only one cell on C10:C20 set to "yes" then the other cell will return to default value.

Comment: @player0 sure, i add to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using Apps Script [onEdit() Simple Trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

### Sample Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var source = e.source;
  var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;

  // Check if modified cell is in C10:C20
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && cell.getRow() >= 10 && cell.getRow() <= 20 && cell.getColumn() == 3) {

    // Set default values in the range
    var defaultValues = new Array(11).fill("Default Value");
    defaultValues = defaultValues.map(val => [val]);
    // Write the default values in the range
    sheet.getRange("C10:C20").setValues(defaultValues);

    //Re-write the modified cell value
    sheet.getRange(cell.getA1Notation()).setValue(e.value);
  }

}
```

### What it does?

- Using onEdit(e) [event object (e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of the modified/edited cell
- Check if the modified cell is within the range that you want, in this example we are using C10:C20, hence we will check the modified cell's row number and column number
- Create a 2-d array values containing your default value
- Write the default values in the range C10:C20
- Re-write the original value in the modified cell.

### Output

[image]